# Custom Document Library - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to create a document library with few managed metadata columns and views (group by, filter etc.) and make this available to the tenant.  I know I can save the 'library as the template' but I will have to upload STP file to each Site Collection.

**Two questions**:

1. Is there any way to create this type of library  and make it available
   across the tenant through apps catalog?
2. Is there any way to classify this library e.g. 'Secure' or 'Project' or 'Public' so I can query it through REST or search? 101 template ID won't work as it will bring all the document libraries.

Any guidance would be much appreciated

Comment: Did you think about creating a content type and publish it from Content type hub?

Comment: @VenkatKonjeti I can use content type hub for documents but I am looking for ways to classify/categorise document libraries e.g. sensitive, public etc.